# Is is possible to display <style> contents as a string?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can display the contents of a function using functionName.toString()

Is is possible to display the contents of the `<style></style>` section?

Using `XXX.toString()`, like maybe: `styleName.toString()`?
Or something else?

I can't figure out how to reference the `<style>` contents.

Comment: Have you tried `document.querySelector("style").innerHTML`?

Comment: Just like getting the contents of any other DOM element as a string.

Comment: Perfect.  Works just fine.

Comment: Where do I indicate the question has been answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `innerHTML` or `innerText` property, just like any other DOM element.

```
document.querySelector("style").innerText
```

If you have multiple `<style>` elements you can give the one you want an ID and use that in the selector. If you want all of them, you can use `document.querySelectorAll("style")` and loop over them.